# Mongodb can't sort russian words properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongomapper

I want to sort records by title. I'm using rails 3 with mongomapper.
And it works great with english words:

```
klass.where(hash).sort({"slug" => -1}).map &:slug
=>  ["yak", "yak", "yag", "ser", "miss"]
```

But there is problem with russian titles. Sorting doesn't work properly:

```
klass.where(hash).sort({"title" => -1}).map &:title
=> ["сэр", "мисс", "Як", "Як", "Яг"] # should be ["Як", "Як", "Яг", "cэр", "мисс"]
```

I know that it's a issue with mongo sorting algorithm, but anyway, maybe someone knows how to solve this? Is there any ruby gem or method, that can fix this?

Comment: This is because MongoDB still does not have collations

Comment: The feature request: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1920

Comment: The technique in this [sorting blog post](http://derickrethans.nl/mongodb-collation.html) can be used as a workaround.